# C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Python/mail_automation/.git: Permission denied

Tags: git

Hola estoy utilizando windows 10 y al intentar hace `git init` me sale este error:

> C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Python/mail_automation/.git: Permission denied

Comment: ¿Y esa carpeta tiene permisos de escritura?, por que debes tener presente que `git init` creará una carpeta a través de la cual transformará dicha carpeta en un proyecto de git

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias.

Comment: No olvides comentar que y como lo solucionaste y asi no queda abierta la pregunta

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es publicar tu propia respuesta, y luego macarla como aceptada.